# PHP fill the missing values with empty values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have the array like

```
array(
    [0] => array(
              [a] => r1,
              [b] => c1,
              [c] => d1,
           ),
    [1] => array(
              [a] => r1,
              [b] => c1,
              [c] => d2,
           ),
    [2] => array(
              [a] => r1,
              [b] => c1,
              [c] => d3,
           ),
    [3] => array(
              [a] => r1,
              [b] => c2,
              [c] => d1,
           ),
    [4] => array(
              [a] => r1,
              [b] => c2,
              [c] => d3,
           ),
    [5] => array(
              [a] => r1,
              [b] => c3,
              [c] => d1,
           )
)
```

Currently I am getting the output like

```
-------------------------------------
|   C1,D1   |   C1,D2   |   C1,D3   |
-------------------------------------
|   C2,D2   |   C3,D1   |     -     |
-------------------------------------
|     -     |     -     |     -     |
-------------------------------------
```

But I need the output must be displayed by 3x3 matrix Like

```
-------------------------------------
|   C1,D1   |   C1,D2   |   C1,D3   |
-------------------------------------
|     -     |   C2,D2   |     -     |
-------------------------------------
|   C3,D1   |     -     |     -     |
-------------------------------------
```

Please help me to fill the missing values with empty values

**My code :**

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
  for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++){
    for($r=0; $r<9; $r++){
      if(isset($rows[$r]) && $rows[$r]['b'] == 'C'.$i && $rows[$r]['c'] == 'D'.$j) {
        //Store data to array
        $data[] = array(
          'a'       => $rows[$r]['a'],
          'b'       => $rows[$r]['b'],
          'c'       => $rows[$r]['c']
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tried code ?

Comment: yes sure... Please wait

Comment: without code is impossible help you!

Comment: @Rikesh I have added code here

Comment: @MoorthyGK I think you might need to explain more the logic behind your output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Option => Fill the array with empty values then fill in the values you got.
2. Option => Remember which index positions you fill and then fill the rest by excluding the ones u filled.

Number 1 is easier.

Number 2 has better performance.

You can use [array_fill](http://www.php.net/array_fill)

or do a loop through the array:

```
for( $i = 0 ; $i < MAX ; $i++ )
   arr[i] = ""; // fill with whatever value you like
```